# Calling a third party QGIS plugin from within a standalone Python script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

In a standalone python script, I would like to use the [Rectanglify QGIS plugin](https://github.com/YoannQDQ/qgis-rectanglify) to create oriented minimum bounding boxes from some polygons, as it is more accurate than the native Oriented Minimum Bounding Boxes tool. However, I have no idea how to call a third party plugin from a script, let alone outside of the QGIS GUI, and the only examples I've been able to find concern natives tools.

How can I get this done?

Comment: How are you running your stand-alone python script?  From a Python IDE, using the Python window inside of QGIS?

Comment: @GBG I am running it from an IDE - Visual Studio Code

Comment: Rectanglify is using QGIS Python libraries.  You would need to ensure that your IDE is pointing to the Python interpreter that QGIS is using.  The library would need to be in the Lib folder of that same interpreter (or in the same directory as your script) to call it with an import statement.  Unsure if Rectaglify can execute from an import statement in your script, that would depend on how the developer coded the tool but presumably they followed Pythonic standards to allow for such an execution.